# TFS source control - new files not automatically detected as pending changes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

As per the tags, I'm using VS2013 and TFS2013.

There are multiple projects in the solution: Model, Presenter, View, etc. All other projects are working as expected in terms of source control operations.

Problems with the Model project:

- Adding a new file via Solution Explorer isn't automatically detected as a pending change
- Deleting a file isn't detected either

Other source control operations work fine for the Model project, such as:

- Get latest version
- Edit detection for existing files (including changes to the csproj
  file when a new file is added)
- Checking in pending changes

The csproj file would show up in pending changes with the newly added file listed in it, but the new file itself isn't showing up, therefore causing build errors on other developers' machines if only the csproj changes are checked in.

The workaround is to find the added file in solution explorer and Add via context menu, this will make it appear as a pending change. But this process should be automatic as per the other projects.

Noticed that there is no .vspscc file for the Model project while other projects have one each.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hi, by any chance are the newly added file in the Excluded section? If you are seeing the issue only on your machine then the TFS source control binding might be broken for the project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would unbind and rebind the problem project and try again:

To **unbind** a solution or project from source control

- In Visual Studio, open Solution Explorer and select a solution or
  project to unbind.
- On the **File** menu, click **Source Control**, then **Change Source Control**.
- In the **Change Source** Control dialog box, click **Unbind**.

To **bind** a solution or project to source control

- In Visual Studio, open Solution Explorer and select a solution or project to bind.
- On the **File** menu, click Source Control, then **Change Source Control**.
- In the **Change Source Control** dialog box, click **Bind**.
- Select the database and location to which to bind, and click OK.
- Click OK.

You might need to go to **Advanced** to find the **Change Source Control** option

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eh3790h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: OK it turns out that the project wasn't bound to source control. I checked this by going to Change Source Control dialog box. I'm guessing the other source control operations worked for the project because source control was only acting as a simple versioning control based on the folder structure, but not knowing that it is a visual studio project. After binding the project to source control, the mentioned problems have been rectified because I guess now the project talks to source control directly when a file is added or deleted.

Answer (score 12):

Before unbinding and binding your solution try this:

1. Go to Source Control Explorer
2. Click the "Add Items to Folder" (the
   one on the left of the red cross)
3. Select the items you want to Add and follow the instructions on screen

That's all

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click <Detected: x add(s), x delete(s)> : in the source control explorer then select the file to add

Answer (score 0):

For years I've been relying on 'Detected Adds' to add missing files - which was never a sustainable solution but I've just about managed with it.

But now if broke.

I'm actually about to reinstall Windows but in the meantime one of the best ways I've found to get a sense on what's missing (and it's still working even though the detected adds isn't) is the recursive 'Compare' window.

You can add files from here too.

[image]

It's a little klunky but it gives me a good sense of security and shows file diffs if you want to see what may have changes.